# Table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents

Does anyone know how to make a table of contents page separately from the others?  For instance: creating a section on table of contents without generating a next page containing this section.

Comment: how do you want to add page's number?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.